# How to create date range day interval for datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker, date-range

I'm using [Pikaday Plugin](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday) and I created booking form as I want and in my opinion it's great for now except one issue.

there is a date range function I set 15 day for between two input date [if you click this link you will see](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/wgLyMw)

and I have same form with auto next focus but I couldn't apply my date-range function for 15 days how can I apply it my code which is in below

[and by the way this is my auto next form link](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/QdXaLZ)

```
function getMaxDate(element){
  if(element.id=='checkout')
    return new Date(new Date(element.parentNode.querySelector('#checkin').value).getTime()+(15*24*60*60*1000));
else
  return new Date(2020, 12, 31);
  }
function getMinDate(element){
  if(element.id=='checkout')
    return new Date(element.parentNode.querySelector('#checkin').value);
  else
  return new Date();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check below code, how we can validate date in 15 days range. you were trying to validate checkout date on load time, so he dint getting checkin date that's why its was not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.flexdatalist').flexdatalist({
    minLength: 0,
    searchContain: true,
  }).on('select:flexdatalist', function() {
    $('#checkin').trigger("click");
  });

  assignPicker = function(id, whenClosed) {
    if (typeof whenClosed !== 'function') {
      whenClosed = null;
    }

    return new Pikaday({
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      field: document.getElementById(id),
      format: "DD.MM.YYYY",
      minDate: new Date(),
      firstDay: 1,
      maxDate: getMaxDate(id),
      onSelect: function() {
        e = this.getDate();
      },
      onSelect: whenClosed
    });
  }

  assignPicker('checkin', function() {

    $('#checkout').trigger("click");
  });
  
  $("#checkout").on('click',function(){
    assignPicker('checkout', function() {
    $('#select').trigger("click");
  });
  })


});
function getMaxDate(id){
  if(id=='checkout')
    return new Date(new Date($('#checkin').val()).getTime()+(15*24*60*60*1000));
else
  return new Date(2020, 12, 31);
  }
```

```css
body {
            padding: 30px;
        }
        input,
        select {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pikaday/1.5.1/css/pikaday.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.anitur.com.tr/example/flexdatalist/flexdatalist.css" />

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        <input type="text" name="" class='flexdatalist' data-min-length='1' list='languages' name='language' />
        <datalist id="languages">
          <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
          <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
          <option value="Cobol">Cobol</option>
          <option value="C#">C#</option>
          <option value="C++">C++</option>
          <option value="Java">Java</option>
          <option value="Pascal">Pascal</option>
          <option value="FORTRAN">FORTRAN</option>
          <option value="Lisp">Lisp</option>
          <option value="Swift">Swift</option>
          <option value="ActionScript">ActionScript</option>
        </datalist>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
          <input type="text" class="checkin" id="checkin" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">

          <input type="text" class="checkout" id="checkout" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">

<form action="" method="get">
        <select name="select" id="select">
          <option value="0">Choose</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
        </select>
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pikaday/1.5.1/pikaday.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.anitur.com.tr/example/flexdatalist/flexdatalist.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes you can replace but make sure if there is some other code accept this above code then take care that code should not be removed FYI